# e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags while trying to repair SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, ssd, ext4

After a couple of force shutdowns of Ubuntu 20.04, I am getting busybox prompt on boot from my 256GB M.2 SATA SSD(sdb).
Booted from another HDD(sda) and Disks is showing the following error when trying to repair the SSD-

```
Error while repairing filesystem

Error repairing filesystem on /dev/sdb5: Process reported exit code 12: e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)

e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdb5 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

There are two petitions on this SSD namely, Root(sdb1) and Home(sdb5).

I am able to mount Root and browse but, not able to mount home.

**Steps I followed so far-**

```
# sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb

fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
```

Tried replacing alternate superblocks with `e2fsck -b 32768 <device>`

None of these worked.

Made a (partial)backup of Root with Backups, I have not tried to format and restore yet.

Is it possible to repair this SSD? What is the exact issue?

Edit:

```
~ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

<removed snaps and loops>

sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 114.5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0   124G  0 part /home
└─sda6   8:6    0 227.3G  0 part /run/timeshift/backup
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0  93.3G  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
└─sdb5   8:21   0 145.2G  0 part
```

```
~ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: OSC M.2 256GB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9c55915b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 195710975 195708928  93.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       195710976 500117503 304406528 145.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       195715072 500117503 304402432 145.2G 83 Linux
```

Edit 1:

```
~ sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sdb1: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdb1


/dev/sdb1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

➜  ~ sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb5
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdb5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (change sda to something else if it named something else after booting to your HDD). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema added response, please check

Comment: Do `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1` and `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema updated

Comment: Sorry my bad, sda1 and sda5 is my HDD which are mounted (e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.) and where my current ubuntu is installed. sdb is my SSD.

Comment: Are you booting to /dev/sda 500G HDD? Is /dev/sdb your normal bootable SSD that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124630/discussion-between-digiwizkid-and-heynnema).

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: @tremby Got a replacement from the manufacturer.